# Overwrite field in queryset annotate

Tags: django

I have a django model with the fields `name` (string) and `value` (integer). Say I need to return a queryset of {name:..., value:...} objects, with each value doubled. What I am trying to do now is:

```py
queryset.annotate(value=F('value') * 2)
```

However, django tells me that the field `value` already exists.

I also tried using extra:

```py
queryset.annotate(value_double=F('value') * 2).extra(select={'value': 'value_double'})
```

but that also does not work since `value_double` is not a valid field.

Of course, in this case I could use something like `queryset.extra(select={'value': 'value * 2'})`, but I have some other, more complicated cases involving a lot of functions where I really don't want to write sql, but I'd rather find a solution in django. Again, in all of my cases, `annotate` works perfectly fine as long as I give the result a new name.

Comment: Why is giving the annotate result a new name a problem for your use case?

Comment: @Chris I am passing a function which returns this queryset (I am trying to implement this function) to another function which expects this exact format and which I cannot easily change

Comment: Does your annotated queryset need to containg the complete model instances or is a a Queryset with certain values sufficient? In the later case I think something like this works: ```queryset.values('name').annotate(value=F('value')*2)```

Comment: @Chris since I am using methods on the model later on, using .values does not really solve the problem for me...

Answer (score 5):

Say your model is XYZ with fields name and  val. If you want val to contain val*2 use below queryset

```
x = XYZ.objects.values('name').annotate(val=F('val')*2)

print(x)
```

Result

```
<QuerySet [{'name': abc, 'val': 104},...............]
```

If you want queryset that return name,val and doubleval. You can use below query for same.

```
x = XYZ.objects.values('name','val',doubleval=F('val')*2)
print(x)
```

Result

```
<QuerySet [{'name': abc, 'val':52,'doubleval': 104},...............]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: the problem is, like mentioned in the comment on my question, I need a queryset of model objects and not just dictionaries...

Comment: A queryset is a list of objects of given model. That is what printed in result. Please provide an example of what output you are expecting here.

Comment: The queryset I get from .values returns a queryset of dictionaries (key-value pairs); I need a queryset of model objects (in your example instances of XYZ) (of course I can instantiate an XYZ from every entry in the queryset, but that defeats the purpose)

Comment: @Lukor - did you find a solution here? We are hoping to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @fullStackChris sadly, I did not; I ended up giving the result a new name...

Comment: There is an open issue on the Django tracker: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28072